# Finding the values from same table that have value 1 and 2 but not 3

Tags: sql

Hi I have the below table where I want to find the object_ida that I have format_id 1,3,11 and 12 but not 10. Could you please help?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `group by` and `having`:

```
select object_id
from t
group by object_id
having sum(case when format_id = 1 then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when format_id = 3 then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when format_id = 11 then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when format_id = 12 then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when format_id = 10 then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```

Each condition tests for one of the `format_id`s.  The `> 0` means that at least one is assigned to an `object_id`.  The `= 0` means that none are assigned.